# Redux-saga call multiple actions/functions in order for a dispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I have a saga and associated tasks like follows

```
function* processRequest() {
  yield takeEvery(ActionTypes.HANDLE_REQUEST, getDuplicate);
  yield takeEvery(ActionTypes.HANDLE_REQUEST, correctData);
}

function* getDuplicate(data: any) {
   const value = yield call(someId);
   const someData = transform(value);// some data manipulation in transform
   yield put(someData);
}

function* correctData(data: any) {
   yield delay(2500)
   let someData = yield select(someProp); //getLatest store data
   someData = transform(value);// some data manipulation in transform
   yield put(someData);
}
```

Is there any way to execute the tasks `getDuplicate` and `correctData` in order without using delay in the second task? Basically treat like the first call is blocking. Also is there any way to combine the two `takeEvery` actions of the same type to one?

Comment: Can you combine your saga watchers into one?